# How to distribute polar and azimuthal angle such that grid elements are of equal solid angle?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Ω = solid angle
θ = polar angle
ψ = azimuth angle

I'm trying to use the formula of dΩ = sinθ dθ dψ to determine dψ and dθ such that each grid element on a 2-D plot of ψ vs θ has an equal solid angle value. I know that ψ can be equally spaced since dΩ is linearly dependent on that, but I'm not quite sure how to handle the polar angle θ and dθ since dΩ is not linearly dependent on that. Intuitively I think the quantity sinθdθ needs to be equally spaced.

To summarize, how can I distribute θ and ψ such that each grid element contains an equal solid angle?

Comment: If you want to pose the question in a way that focuses on the role of $\theta$, consider the following problem on a sphere. How would you choose $n$ lines of latitude such that each pair of adjacent lines contains the same surface area?

Comment: Semiclassical, I think you're essentially posing the same question I've asked. Intuitively, I can reason that the distance between adjacent lines is going to increase from equator to pole. Not sure if this is correct or how to represent this mathematically.